# backbone js this.model.get is not a function

Tags: javascript, html, backbone.js

Started with backbone js and already ran into a trouble.

Here is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Backbone training</title>
        <script src="jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>
        <script src="underscore.js"></script>
        <script src="backbone.js"></script>
        <style type="text/css">
            .rectangle{
                position: absolute;
                border: 4px solid #000000;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Rectangles</h1>
        <div id="canvas"></div>
    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="rectangles.js"></script>
</html>
```

Here is rectangles.js file content:

```
(function () {

    var Rectangle = Backbone.Model.extend({});

    var RectangleView = Backbone.View.extend({

        tagName: 'div',
        className: 'rectangle',
        render: function() {
            this.setDimensions();
            this.setPostion();
            return this;
        },

        setDimensions: function() {
            this.$el.css({
                width: this.model.get('width') + 'px',
                height: this.model.get('height') + 'px'
            });
        },

        setPostion: function() {
            var position = this.model.get('position');
            this.$el.css({
                left: position.x,
                top: position.y
            });
        }

    });

    var myRectangle = new Rectangle({
        width: 100,
        height: 60,
        position: {
            x: 300,
            y: 150
        }
    });

    var myView = new RectangleView({model: 'myRectangle'});

    $('div#canvas').append(myView.render().el);


})();
```

Once I run it I get this error: **TypeError: this.model.get is not a function**
As it is tutorial material I assume it should be okay, at least it is okay for the guy in the video. Thought I missed something, so tried to rewrite it few times with no luck. As a newbie in backbone stuff I am not sure where I went wrong?

Any links or suggestions are much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass the instance of the model into the view, here:

```
var myView = new RectangleView({model: 'myRectangle'});
```

should become:

```
var myView = new RectangleView({model: myRectangle});
```

Simply passing the name as a string is not enough, Backbone doesn't know what variable you assigned the `new Rectangle` to or what it should look for.

You may also want to revise your `render` method; I believe the conventional Backbone way is to have the view take an element (`el` or `$el`) when it is constructed, then render into that element when render is called (rather than producing a new element and returning that).

Comment: Uhh, this is really shameful to miss out such a detail. Thank you for taking time to review it and respond and big thanks for suggestions! :)